# unix command to read line from a file by passing line number

Tags: unix

I am looking for a unix command to get a single line by passing line number to a big file (with around 5 million records). For example to get 10th line, I want to do something like

```
command file-name 10
```

Is there any such command available? We can do this by looping through each record but that will be time consuming process.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This [forum entry](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-read-a-given-line-number-from-text-264645/) suggests:

```
sed -n '52p' (file)
```

for printing the 52th line of a file.

Comment: Why the ()? That gives my bash version an error, might have been corrected in later versions though.

Comment: He means to have you replace (file) with the file

Comment: I was able to speed this up by a factor of ten (when used with a file with 100000 lines) by quitting after printing: `sed -n '52{p;q}'`

Comment: @Philipp, Yes, however that won't on all sed versions, I believe that's GNU sed specific.

Answer (score 6):

Going forward, There are a lot of ways to do it, and other related stuffs.

If you want multiple lines to be printed,

```
sed -n -e 'Np' -e 'Mp'
```

Where N and M are lines which will only be printed. Refer this [10 Awesome Examples for Viewing Huge Log Files in Unix](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/08/10-awesome-examples-for-viewing-huge-log-files-in-unix/)

Comment: what if I want more than one records from 1000 lines of file? how can I pass multiple number of lines in this commnd?

Answer (score 2):

```
command | sed -n '10p'
```

or

```
sed -n '10p' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
head -n<lineno> <file> | tail -n1
```

That would give you the `<lineno>` lines, then only give the last line of output (your line).

**Edit**: It seems all the solutions here are pretty slow.  However, by definition you'll have to iterate through all the records since the operating system has no way to parse line-oriented files since files are byte-oriented.  (In some sense, all these programs are going to do is count the number of `\n` or `\r` characters.)  In lieu of a great answer, I'll also present the timings on my system of several of these commands!

```
[mjschultz@mawdryn ~]$ time sed -n '145430980p' br.txt
0b10010011111111010001101111010111

real    0m25.871s
user    0m17.315s
sys 0m2.360s
[mjschultz@mawdryn ~]$ time head -n 145430980 br.txt | tail -n1
0b10010011111111010001101111010111

real    0m41.112s
user    0m39.385s
sys 0m4.291s
[mjschultz@mawdryn ~]$ time awk 'NR==145430980{print;exit}' br.txt 
0b10010011111111010001101111010111

real    2m8.835s
user    1m38.076s
sys 0m3.337s
```

So, on my system, it looks like the `sed -n '<lineno>p' <file>` solution is fastest!

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk

```
awk 'NR==10{print;exit}' file
```

Put an exit after printing the 10th line so that awk won't process the 5 million records file further.