# Get a specific line of a file in Unix

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to extract specific lines (say lines 2, and 4 through 6) from a file and redirect them to a file in the command line / pipe it to another program.

Which tool would do the job the fastest / cleanest (sed, awk, perl, shell)?

Comment: Why is Perl a bad tag?  And how can I improve this question?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little shocked that this isn't a dupe – it's essentially a classic question. But I don't think it's a *bad* question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unix command to read line from a file by passing line number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286084/unix-command-to-read-line-from-a-file-by-passing-line-number)

Comment: Not completely a dupe, though, since this question asks how to get one line, then, later, a range.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this question as phrased comes across as shopping (because it implies you already know which tools are available and just want to know which *is best*). It might be better to simply ask how to pick arbitrary lines (both individual lines and ranges) out of a file and not assume anything about the toolchain. The part about cleanliness and speed should go without saying.

Answer (score 6):

Sed has a nice way of doing this:

```
sed -ne '2p' -e '4,6p'
```

for example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..100} | sed -ne '2p' -e '4,6p'
2
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk` and its parameter `NR`. You can compose conditional expressions such as:

```
$ cat a
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
$ awk 'NR==3' a #print line number 3
cc
$ awk 'NR==3, NR==5' a #print from line number 3 up to number 5
cc
dd
ee
$ awk 'NR>2 && NR<7' a #print lines whose number is in the range (2,7)
cc
dd
ee
```

etc.

In your case,

```
$ awk 'NR==2; NR>=4 && NR<=6' a #print line number 2 and from 4 to 6
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'NR==2 || NR>=4 && NR<=6'
```

or

```
awk 'NR==2; NR==4,NR==6'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using just `head` and `tail` ...

For example:

```
NR=3; cat test.txt | head -n $NR | tail -n -1
```

extracts line 3 from `test.txt`; and

```
NB=2; NR=3; cat test.txt | head -n $(expr $NR \+ $NB) | tail -n -$NB
```

extracts line 3 to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk and keep it clear and simple:

```
awk 'NR==2 || (NR>=4 && NR<=6)' file
```